# Compiling YouCompleteMe on Windows gives "CM libraries found in old YouCompleteMe/python location" error

Tags: windows, vim

I've followed [these directions exactly](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide#instructions-for-64-bit-using-mingw64-clang).

I was able to compile mingw32-make ycm_support_libs and it produced the necessary `ycm_core.pyd`, `ycm_client_support.pyd`, and `libclang.dll` files.  However, I get this message when starting vim:

```
YCM libraries found in old YouCompleteMe/python location; please RECOMPILE YCM.
```

I have verified that all the tools I've used are 64bit version.  Anything I find on the web about this just says to run `./install.sh --clang-completer`, which should be doing exactly what `mingw32-make ycm_support_libs` does.

I was so close too!  Any help?

Comment: Yes, you can find help on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues).

Comment: The only stuff in there I found said "This is windows.  Windows isn't official supported.  Closed." which didnt help too much.

Comment: It's at the bottom.  Here's the link : https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1172

Comment: Looks like I just need to move the compiled code to a different folder.

Comment: Have u solved this problem. I'm getting the same error. i'm using precompiled ycm from https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/vim-youcompleteme-for-windows. Can u help. I've wasted a  lot of time on this.

Comment: Actually yes, the link posted above about the folder was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The file that is produced from the compile doesn't need to be moved.  This was an old instruction that is now obsolete.  I've managed to get C/C++ auto-complete working on Windows 7.

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1172

From the above link: Oh I see... sorry :P Anyway I don't know when was the last time someone modified the wiki page on installing YCM on Windows. The wiki page is community maintained. The error is caused by the fact that before YCM was splitted in two repo (this one for the vim client, and one for the general backend, ycmd) the compiled libraries were putted in YouCompleteMe/python now instead are putted in YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd. Anyway we can continue to discuss this but I have to close this issue since is not a YCM bug and Windows is not supported officially.